# T-SQL: how to number items in non-unique groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

There's a table that logs the user logins.

The columns are:

UserID, Date, IsSuccessful (bit)

I need to find those users who have 3+ failed attepts to log in in a row.

I tried this:

```
select  UserID, Date, IsSuccessful,
        count(*) over ( partition by UserID, IsSuccessful order by Date ) Cnt
from    UserLogins
order   by UserID, Date
```

The Cnt column shows the sequential number of the IsSuccessful value, but it doesn't restart at a group change:

```
UserID, IsSuccessful, Cnt
555, 1, 1
555, 1, 2
555, 1, 3
555, 0, 1
555, 0, 2
555, 1, 4
555, 0, 3
555, 1, 5
555, 1, 6
555, 1, 7
555, 0, 4
555, 0, 5
555, 0, 6
555, 1, 8
```

What I need is as follows:

```
UserID, IsSuccessful, Cnt
555, 1, 1
555, 1, 2
555, 1, 3
555, 0, 1
555, 0, 2
555, 1, 1
555, 0, 1
555, 1, 1
555, 1, 2
555, 1, 3
555, 0, 1
555, 0, 2
555, 0, 3
555, 1, 1
```

Comment: The `UserID` value is missing from you sample data.

Comment: Right you are. The sample data is for a single specific user.

Comment: The date column is also missing.

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't matter what specific values there are in the Date column. It is only used for ordering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT UserID, [Date], IsSuccessful,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID, IsSuccessful, grp 
                          ORDER BY [Date]) AS cnt
FROM (
  SELECT UserID, [Date], IsSuccessful,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID 
                            ORDER BY [Date]) -
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID, IsSuccessful 
                            ORDER BY [Date]) AS grp
FROM UserLogins) AS t
```

Comment: Almost works (and upvoted), but doesn't quite give the output requested in the question. In the question the results are in date order, but when I tried it they weren't. All the failures were first, then all the successes. `ORDER BY t.[Date]` fixes it.

Comment: Thanks @Andy, the final ORDER BY clause would make the output more clear for a human. Nevertheless, the Giorgos' query generally solves the task: the Cnt column is calculated correctly, and that's what the question was about. While the order of data doesn't really matter to me, as the Cnt column will be used for filtering.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, that is less general, but solves my specific task (detect 3 failures in a row):

```
select  UserID, [Date], IsSuccessful,
        SUM( 1 - CAST(IsSuccessful AS INT) ) OVER( PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY DATE ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS NumberOfFailures
from    UserLogins
order   by UserID, [Date]
```